# Is there a way for classes to communicate with one another without connecting them through object references?

Tags: c#, oop, scope

The hardest problem I'm having is illustrating the problem. It runs, but it feels like there's a much cleaner way to achieve the same thing. Is there a way for a method in one class to communicate with another object, without having to create a reference to that object as a property in the class? For instance, here's a very simplified example. I'd like to create a shelter object that stores pets. As well, I have a class that wants to interact with the shelter, potentially adding a pet to the shelter's list of pets. Is this only achievable through referencing the shelter on the encounter object? This doesn't feel like it scales well when we need one object to interact with many others, or many objects to interact with this one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static Shelter shelter;
    static Encounter encounter;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // this is what I'd like to avoid
        encounter = new Encounter();
        encounter.shelter = shelter;
    }
}

class Pet
{
    string name;
    public Pet()
    {
        name = "DefaultDog";
    }
}

class Shelter
{
    public List<Pet> pets;
    public void AddPet(Pet pet)
    {
        pets.Add(pet);
    }
}

class Encounter
{
    // this is what I'd like to avoid
    public Shelter shelter;
    public void CapturePet()
    {

        shelter.AddPet(new Pet());
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Well the `Encounter.CapturePet` method has to have *some* reference to a `Shelter` object... otherwise if you'd created two `Shelter` objects, how would you expect it to know which one to add the pet to? Now that doesn't mean it has to be a field... you could pass it via a parameter in the `CapturePet` method for example. But there's got to be a reference somewhere.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I knew there needed to be a reference to the object, but wasn't sure as to where that reference was best placed. Which do you think would be preferable?

Comment: We really can't tell with such a small example, to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use delegates, you can achieve the results you want without having to add any class references in the Encounter class. Delegates provide you with the flexibility necessary to add pets to as many shelters as you wish, as well as any other kind of side effects. You can read more about them here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SODelegate
{
    class Program
    {
        static Shelter shelter = new();
        static Shelter anotherShelter = new();
        static Encounter encounter = new();


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            encounter.OnCapturePet += delegate (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running first delegate");
                shelter.AddPet(new Pet());
            };
            encounter.OnCapturePet += delegate (object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running second delegate");
                anotherShelter.AddPet(new Pet());
            };

            encounter.CapturePet();
        }
    }


    class Pet
    {
        string name;
        public Pet()
        {
            name = "DefaultDog";
        }
    }

    class Shelter
    {
        public List<Pet> pets = new();
        public void AddPet(Pet pet)
        {
            pets.Add(pet);
        }
    }

    class Encounter
    {
        public event EventHandler OnCapturePet;

        public void CapturePet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running capture pet");
            this.OnCapturePet(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually isn't valid as is-- you've got to create an instance of the `Encounter` class, which will typically look something like this:

```
encounter = new Encounter();
```

This is where you're supposed to initialize and create that encounter. And if an encounter isn't valid with a shelter, you have to provide it. In this case it is idiomatic to pass it as an argument to the constructor:

```
shelter = new Shelter();
encounter = new Encounter(shelter);
```

The constructor might look like this:

```
class Encounter
{
    protected readonly Shelter _shelter;

    public Encounter(Shelter shelter)
    {
        _shelter = shelter;
    }
}
```

Now your encounter always knows what shelter it is associated with by accessing its own `_shelter` field.

To answer your question-- is there some way for your `Shelter` to automatically figure out what `Encounter` it goes with? The answer is no. This is because you can have more than one shelter.

```
var shelters = new List<Shelter>();    
shelters.Add(new Shelter());
shelters.Add(new Shelter());

var encounter = new Encounter();  //Which shelter is this associated with?
```

You have to tell it which one:

```
var shelters = new List<Shelter>();    
shelters.Add(new Shelter());
shelters.Add(new Shelter());

var encounter = new Encounter(shelters[0]);
```

Comment: I made a few edits to reflect the errors you found, thanks! So is it standard to have those references stored as properties, or would it be better to expect the object you'd like to manipulate as a parameter to some sort of method?

Comment: If it's inextricably part of the object then it belongs as a property (e.g. a `TextBox` has properties for its `Text`, `Width`, `Position` etc); if it isn't part of the object, but simply needed to process a specific function, pass it in as an argument (e.g. a `TextBox` might have a `void Paint(Graphics gr)` method that accepts the graphics context to paint itself into).